# Databricks notebook %run relative path, not working for 3 level deep

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I need to run a databricks notebook 3 folder levels up with relative path but it is not working.

Is it a limitation? It works if I specify full path..

This is what I have tested:

`%run ./folder/notebook` - WORKS

`%run ../folder/notebook` - WORKS

`%run .../folder/notebook` - not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `...` to specify level - you need to use two of `..` for that, like this:

```
../../folder/notebook
```

It's the standard Unix & DOS notation for relative paths (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths))

If you need to go to more levels, just add more `../`

Comment: Many thanks @Alex Ott for teaching me something new today :) !